# Is there a way to schedule Jupyter Notebook to run automatically every 2 minutes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am working on a project where I need to push a data into an api using Jupyter notebook every 2 minutes. Is there a way to schedule a notebook automatically to run every 2 minutes?
I have a notebook with a working code but i just need to run everything in it every 2 minutes.

I am using Windows 10 and Anaconda 3.7. 
I tried running Windows Scheduler, but i see the limitation of 5 minutes.

Comment: crontab is suggested.
But you need some time to learn it.

Comment: Do you actually need to run the entire notebook, not just a regular Python script/application?

Comment: @appleyuchi crontab is not available on Windows

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have only worked with Jupyter notebook. I am allowed to use other applications as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think a good way would to take all the code from your `Jupyter notebook` and make a python file out of it. Let's say the function you make is called `run`.

You can then do something like

```
import 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        run()
        time.sleep(2 * 60)
```

Comment: This works fine, but it just runs the block of code for two minutes. Is there a way to schedule the code, so I can refresh it every 2 minutes? Thanks